Asking question about a man not working and delivering all work to his wife
I know some family with a caring and working wife but a good-for-nothing husband.
The children are now grown up and at least one is able and willing to care for himself.
Not so the husband.
My question is: is this a question to be ask on this site, or to consult a mufti (by myself, as the wife would not dare).

Interesting question: I'd say (and this is my subjective opinion) it is at least somewhat an  opinion-based topic: Either you are a modern person seeing no harm in a working wife or not. However, the tendency is that the husband has the duty to be in charge of the family I'd say this is the strongest view on fiqh. It remains somehow subjective, depending on the effort this husband is making to get a job or at least because at the end somebody must feed the family.

@Medi1Saif that is but one reason why I once asked how to find a mufti.
